What does it mean to say that a statistical model is a location family?
I would like to know what it means to say that a statistical model is a location family. Looking at some definitions, I came up with three possible interpretations of the definition of location family.
Let $(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}_\mathbb{R},P_\theta )_{\theta\in\Theta }$ be a statistical model in which $\mathfrak{B}_\mathbb{R}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. For all $\theta$ define $F_\theta :\mathbb{R\to R}$ by $F_\theta (x):=P_\theta ((-\infty ,x])$.
My question: which of the following definitions is the correct one?
Definition 1: We say that $(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}_\mathbb{R},P_\theta )_{\theta\in\Theta }$ is a location family if for any $\theta\in\Theta$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the function $F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $F(x):=F\!_{\theta} (x+a)$ belongs to the set $\{F_\theta\}_{\theta\in\Theta }$.
Definition 2: We say that $(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}_\mathbb{R},P_\theta )_{\theta\in\Theta }$ is a location family if there's $\theta_0\in\Theta$ such that for all $\theta\in\Theta$ there's $a_\theta \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $F_\theta (x)=F_{\theta_0}(x-a_\theta )$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Definition 3: We say that $(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}_\mathbb{R},P_\theta )_{\theta\in\Theta }$ is a location family if there's $\theta_0\in\Theta$ such that the following propositions are true:

For all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the function $F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $F(x):=F\!_{\theta_0} (x+a)$ belongs to the set $\{F_\theta\}_{\theta\in\Theta }$;
For all $\theta\in\Theta$ there's $a_\theta \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $F_\theta (x)=F_{\theta_0}(x-a_\theta )$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Using, for instance, the definition 2, it's easy to that the statistical model $ (\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}_\mathbb{R},N(\mu ,\sigma ^2))_{\mu \in\mathbb{R}}$ (with $\sigma^2>0$ fixed) is a location family.

In order to have a formal treatment of location families of distributions, one must reckon with how a group of transformations acts on a random variable with certain distribution to generate a family of distributions.
Consider a random variable $X$ taking values in $\mathcal X\subseteq \mathrm{l\!R}$ having density $p_0(x).$
Definition $1:$ A transformation group $\mathcal G$ is a group of one-to-one transformations from $\mathcal X$ onto itself.
Definition $2:$ A simple group family $\mathcal F_{\mathcal G}$ generated by $p_0$ is the collection of densities generated by $p_0$ under the group action of $\mathcal G .$
That is, $\mathcal F_{\mathcal G}:= \{g p_0\mid g\in\mathcal G\},$ where $p_g := gp_0$ is the density of $g X.$
It would be assumed that $\mathcal F_{\mathcal G}$  is identifiable.
Now is there any way to identify a class of distributions being a group family or not?
Definition $3:$ A family of distributions $\mathcal F$ is an invariant family under the action of a transformation group $\mathcal G$ if for every $g\in \mathcal G$ and $P\in \mathcal F,$ it is true that $Pg^{-1}\in\mathcal F.$
This induces another transformation viz, $\tilde g: \mathcal F\to\mathcal F; ~ P\mapsto Pg^{-1}.$
$\mathcal P$ in the above definition need not be parametric. However, assume it is, that is $\mathcal F$ is indexed by $\theta\in\Theta .$  Then the definition implies $P_{\tilde g\theta}(A)= P_{\theta}(g^{-1}A) $ or for an integrable $\psi,$ $$\mathbb E_\theta[\psi(gX)] = \mathbb E_{\tilde g\theta}[\psi(X)].$$
If $\tilde g$ is one-to-one (this is ensured by the assumption of identifiability of $\mathcal F$), then $\tilde{\mathcal G} := \{\tilde g\mid g\in\mathcal G\}$ is itself a group of transformations.
Returning to the question raised, the answer to that lies in connection between invariant families and group families:
First assume $\mathcal F = \{P_\theta\mid \theta\in \Theta\}$ is invariant under the action of $\mathcal G$ and that the action of $\tilde{\mathcal G}$ on $\Theta$ is transitive. Fix $p_0 (x)= p(x; \theta_0)$ for some arbitrarily chosen $\theta_0\in\Theta.$ Then the class of densities generated by $p_0$ under the action of $\mathcal G$ that is, $\mathcal F_{\mathcal G} := \{gp_0(x)\mid g\in\mathcal G\}=\left\{ p(x; \tilde g\theta_0)\mid \tilde g\in \tilde{\mathcal G}\right\}$ is a simple group family.
Conversely, a simple group family $\mathcal F_\mathcal G =\{P_g \mid g\in \mathcal G\}$ is invariant under $\mathcal G;$ the elements $g$ can be put in one-to-one correspondence with elements of an indexing set $\Theta$ (that is, $\cal G$ can be taken as the parameter space)  and owing to the closure property, the action of $\mathcal G$ is also transitive.
This leads to the conclusion that a family $\mathcal F$ is a group family, if and only if, there is a group $\mathcal G$ that acts transitively on $\mathcal F$, or that $\tilde{\mathcal G}$ acts transitively on $\Theta.$ To reframe this to answer the question, a family of distributions is a simple group family if and only if it is invariant under a transitive group of transformations.
However, in general, a family invariant under a group need not be subject to a transitive action. Examples could be
$\bullet$ $X\sim\mathsf{Bin}(n, p)$ and letting $gX:= n-X~\wedge~\tilde g p := 1-p;$ the resulting action is not transitive as for each $p\in(0,1),$ one gets the orbit $\{p, 1-p\};$
$\bullet $ $X\sim\mathsf N(\mu, \sigma^2);$ consider the group action $gX:= aX~\wedge~\tilde g(\mu, \sigma^2):= (a\mu, a^2\sigma^2)$ for $a> 0;$ it is clear that it is invariant but the action is not transitive -- an orbit is characterized by the value of $\mu/\sigma.$
Finally, coming specifically to the question, a location family generated by $p_0$ of $X$ is defined as the family $$\mathcal F_{\mathrm l}:=\{p_0(x-\mu)\mid \mu\in\mathrm{l\!R}, ~x\in \mathcal X_\mu\}$$ with $\mathcal X_\mu:= \mu + \mathcal X,$ which is the support of $\mu +X.$  If $p_0(x) = p(x;\mu),$ then the group action  $gX = X+\mu'  $ with the corresponding $\tilde g\theta = \mu +\mu'$ on the parameter space $\Theta:= \mathrm{l\!R}$ is transitive.
--
References:
$\rm[1]$ Principles of Statistical Inference: From a Neo-Fisherian Perspective, Luigi Pace, Alessandra Salvan, World Scientific, $1997,$ sec. $7.1, 7.4.$
$\rm[II]$ Theory of Point Estimation, E. L. Lehmann, George Casella, Springer-Verlag, $1998,$ sec. $3.2.$

Thank you for your answer! Just to make sure: this group action doesn't to have only one orbit, correct? Reading the Example 4.1 (pg 17 of the book Theory of Point Estimation) I believe that the group action must induce only one orbit.

Wikipedia, it turns out, just adds to confusion by providing several inequivalent definitions!  Some (most?) authorities insist on a single orbit: that is, it must be a transitive action.  According to the present answer, the set of all distributions is a location family, but I doubt most people would think of it that way.

See the Wikipedia article, to wit: "a class Ω of probability distributions is a location–scale family if for all cumulative distribution functions F ∈ Ω and any real numbers a ∈ R and b > 0, the distribution function G ( x ) = F ( a + b x ) is also a member of Ω."

It is clear that the group action $g\circ(\mu, \sigma) :=(\mu'+\sigma'\mu, \sigma'\sigma)$ on $\Theta:={(\mu,\sigma)\in\mathrm{l!R}\times\mathrm{l! R}^+}$ is transitive.

That does not describe the group action: it only describes how the group acts on itself.  The group acts on the family of distributions.  When there are two or more members of the family corresponding to a value of $(\mu,\sigma),$ the action will not be transitive.  As an example, one can extend the family of Gamma distributions to include a location parameter, but two Gamma distributions with differing shape parameters will not ever correspond under the group action, demonstrating the action is not transitive.

Felt the answer a bit botched and incomplete. Substantially edited the body.

@rfloc, to answer your initial query, yes group actions needn't be transitive as I mentioned two examples above (borrowed from TPE). But for a simple group family, the group action has to be transitive.

The standard term for your "simple group family" is orbit. The question remains (whose answer I don't know): is there a conventional, widely-accepted definition of "location-scale family"?  If so, does it require the group action to be transitive (that is, there is a unique orbit) or not?

At this point, as I have showed in the argument, it has to be transitive as presented in Casella as well as other sources. I have not found any compelling reason to believe otherwise. If you have anything, please let me know @whuber.

I have twice already directed your attention to the Wikipedia article.  I don't say it's compelling, but it makes one pause and consider researching the question a little more deeply.  Lehmann and Casella is a good reference.

Yes, @whuber. What I meant is whether you know any different source or whether you have any different argument. I have not found any deficiency in the arguments presented in TPE as well as the other sources that showed why it has to be transitive.

Sure @whuber. I got your point. Just that I could not convince myself much against it (transitive ness). But if someone else is able to shed light on this, I would be eager to look into that.

Because it's a matter of terminology, I cannot come up with any argument for or against the transitivity requirement.  Both versions of the concept are useful.  Consequently, the take-home message for me in this thread is to be careful that we understand what specifically is meant when someone refers to a "location-scale family."
